# Matrix rearrangement in R

Tags: r, matrix

If I have a matrix such as

```
      A   B   F
   1 .5  .25  .4
   2 .25  .3  .1
   3 .15  .2   .3
```

I wish to create something of the form of a data frame such as

```
   1    A   .5
   2    A   .25
   3    A   .15
   1    B   .25
   2    B   .3
```

etc.. I have tried using the reshape package with no luck and was wondering if there was a way to do this in R.

Comment: Use `stack(as.data.frame(temp))` where temp is the name of your matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exploit the fact that matrices in R are really just vectors that have a `dim` (i.e., dimensions) attribute applied to them.

In the example below, I assume that you have a matrix with *named* dimensions as is suggested in your question.

```
mat <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3, dimnames=list(1:3,c("A","B","F")))

#   A B F
# 1 1 4 7
# 2 2 5 8
# 3 3 6 9

# get names of dimensions
rows <- as.numeric(rownames(mat))
cols <- colnames(mat)

# reshape
dat <- data.frame( row=rep(rows, times=ncol(mat)),
                   col=rep(cols, each=nrow(mat)),
                   value=as.vector(mat) )

#   row col value
# 1   1   A     1
# 2   2   A     2
# 3   3   A     3
# 4   1   B     4
# 5   2   B     5
# 6   3   B     6
# 7   1   F     7
# 8   2   F     8
# 9   3   F     9
```